# Uploaded php file gets permission 600 (can't execute)

Tags: php, apache, permissions

When I upload php file to server it gets permission 600 (not executable, not readable). Until two days ago everything worked fine.

Please help me

Comment: 600 is readable by the user who owns it. Your server admins may have instated a new file create mask as a security measure.  use [`chmod()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to change the files permissions to what you need after uploading it.

Comment: I am the server admin and all I did was removing disable_function from php.ini. I'm uploading files with FTP protocol

Comment: Tangential note: PHP scripts usually don't need to be executable.

Comment: Which Operating System is your server running? Sounds more like a question for Serverfault to me. And which FTP client are you using?

Comment: are you 100% sure the files exist ? and the path is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the UMASK in your FTP server config. Sounds like it is set to 177 or something.

Have you performed any upgrades/updates to your config?

Also, what FTP client and server are you using?

Switch to SFTP if you have shell access to the box. It is more secure and removes a lot of the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround: You can change the rights directly via php:

```
chmod("myfile.pdf", 0755);
```

See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php